# How to pass docker password to jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

Hi I am new to Devops and I am trying to create a simple Jenkins Pipleine. In which I need to push the docker image to dockerhub. Entire pipeline including Jenkins is hosted on Kubernetes.
Below is the Jenkinsfile. I am giving the credentials inline which is bad. I have stored my dockerhub password in Jenkins as a secret text, but not sure how to reference it here.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml '''
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: docker
            image: docker:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
            volumeMounts:
             - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
               name: docker-sock
          volumes:
          - name: docker-sock
            hostPath:
              path: /var/run/docker.sock    
        '''
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Clone') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          git branch: 'main', changelog: false, poll: false, url: '<my github URL>'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Build-Docker-Image') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'docker build -t <my-dockerhub-username>/testing-image:latest .'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Login-Into-Docker') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'docker login -u <my-dockerhub-username> -p <my-dockerhub-password>'
      }
    }
    }
     stage('Push-Images-Docker-to-DockerHub') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'docker push <my-dockerhub-username>/testing-image:latest'
      }
    }
     }
    stage('Remove docker Images') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'docker image prune -af'
      }
    }
     }
  }
  
    post {
      always {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'docker logout'
      }
      }
    }
}
```

I tried

```
   stage('Push-Images-Docker-to-DockerHub') {
          steps {
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'Docker_PW', variable: 'Docker_PW')])
            container('docker') {
              sh 'docker push <my-dockerhub-username>/testing-image:latest'
          }
        }
         }
```

But my pipeline fails after coming to this step. Please assist if possible.

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry shows how to use your JP credentials for a Docker registry.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
environment {
        DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS=credentials('dockerhub')
}
stages {
        
        stage('gitclone') {
                  ...
        }

        
        stage('Login') {

            steps {
                sh 'echo $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin'
            }
        }

        stage('Push') {
            ...
        }
}
```

Refers to: https://github.com/shazforiot/How-to-Push-docker-image-to-Docker-Hub-using-Jenkins-Pipeline/blob/main/Jenkinsfile